# Unable to write dataframe to cassandra using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, amazon-emr, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to write a dataframe to cassandra using pyspark but its thworing me an error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o74.save.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 6 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3
>   in stage 3.0 (TID 24, ip-172-31-11-193.us-west-2.compute.internal,
>   executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder
>           at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsSupport$class.$init$(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:107)
>           at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsUpdater.(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:153)
>           at org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$.apply(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:75)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:209)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:197)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:183)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Below is my code for write:

```py
DataFrame.write.format(
   "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra"
).mode(
   'append'
).options(
   table="student1", 
   keyspace="university"
).save()
```

I have added the below mentioned spark-caasandra connector in spark-default.conf

spark.jars.packages   datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.4.0-s_2.11

I am able to read the data from cassandra but issue is with write.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of Spark, but this might help:

> These errors are commonly thrown when the Spark Cassandra Connector or
>   its dependencies are not on the runtime classpath of the Spark
>   Application. This is usually caused by not using the prescribed
>   --packages method of adding the Spark Cassandra Connector and its dependencies to the runtime classpath.

Source: 
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#why-cant-the-spark-job-find-spark-cassandra-connector-classes-classnotfound-exceptions-for-scc-classes